# How to share data among the controllers using $broadcast, $on and $emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I am new to AngularJS web development.

STEP 1. During initialization, I get login information from a server with http call. Say, UserName, UserID and some other information.

STEP 2. After successful http call, I would like to populate the loginObj object such as

```
$scope.loginObj = { UserID = '', UserName = '', SomeData: '' };

$scope.loginObj.UserID = 1000;

$scope.loginObj.UserName = 'John Doe';

$scope.loginObj.SomeData = 'Some other data';
```

STEP 3. I would like to broadcast $scope.loginObj object information with 
            $rootScope.broadcast method.

All the examples I have seen used some kind of click button. No Button Click 
solution.

STEP 4. In the child controller, I would like to receive the broadcasted 
            information from the Parent Controller.

```
    How can I receive this information?
```

STEP 5. Some times I get some extra information at the Child Controller as well.

How can I receive this information from Child controller to the Parent 
Controller?

Please provide me a solution or direct me some sites where I can get the example.

Comment: have u tried implementing $broadcast, $on and $emit? If so, please share the code on how you implemented that. We'll take it from there . OR provide a basic plunkr demo code with controller structures and update your question.

Comment: A child controller can just inherit data from a parent controller. Why do you feel you need to use the $scope/$rootScope event bus for this?

Comment: @georgeawg, You are correct and am using it. The structure is Home/Page2/Page3/Page4. If you just click any Page, I get the rootScope values without any problem. The problem I face is once you refresh the page2, I lose the value. It seems to me it is kind of timer issue. If I put alert Home controller, then I get to see the values in Page2 controller. I am missing something here. Please help me out. I am using ng-view in Home page. So, any refresh has to go through Home page before coming to either Page2/Page3.

Comment: @ShashankVivek, Could you please look at my reply to georgeawg and guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Alomoni: sure, can you please provide a demo code on https://plnkr.co/edit/. With `refresh the page2, I lose the value` , do you mean site reload , if thats the case then it'll be lost because your `app` is reloaded entirely. If you want some event to be emitted on reload, may you can out that code in `ng-init` of `HomeController`. For a quick solution , create a working plunkr demo where we can replicate and see what are you implementing

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using broadcast, create an angularjs service in which you persist the login info you got from http call and you can inject this service in the controller in which you need login info.

create a service like this :

```
/*app is your angular module name*/
app.factory('authFactory',['$state',function( $state){
    var authFactory = {

          currentUser: {},

          setCurrentUser: function(userinfo){

             authFactory.currentUser = userinfo;

            },

          getCurrentUser: function(){

            return authFactory.currentUser;
           }
      };

      return authFactory;

}
```

in your login controller, inject authFactory, then once user is logged in, call authFactory.setCurrentUser and pass an object ({login: userlogin, email: useremail}). if you need the logged in user in another page, just inject authFactory in that page and call authFactory.getCurrentUser().

Comment: I have read about the service but haven't seen any example about that. You log on with your info and land onto Home page. Click to 2nd page and refresh the page. Do you think I will have the same login info? Or another http call to get the login info? Please provide me a solution.

Comment: 2nd scenerio You log onto the site with Admin role and land onto the another page because you want to impersonate for another user such as John Doe. In this screen, you provide John Doe unique number and bring the relevant information for John Doe. Here authenticated User = Admin but Regular User would be John Doe because you are trying to update/check John  Doe record. How can I persist this new login information?